# How to stop SSH passphrase prompt?

Tags: ssh

I have a server I just opened. When I ssh as `nt_deployer`, it asks me for an ssh passphrase:

```
Nets-Mac-Pro:mysite emai$ ssh nt_deployer@mysite-staging.nettheory.com
Enter passphrase for key '/Users/emai/.ssh/id_rsa': 
nt_deployer@mysite-staging.nettheory.com's password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-29-generic x86_64)
```

However, when I ssh as `emai`, it doesn't ask:

```
Nets-Mac-Pro:mysite emai$ ssh emai@mysite-staging.nettheory.com
emai@mysite-staging.nettheory.com's password: 
Welcome to Ubuntu 14.04 LTS (GNU/Linux 3.13.0-29-generic x86_64)
```

Can someone tell me how I would stop the passphrase prompt from popping up for `nt_deployer`?

Comment: I ran `ssh-keygen` and it worked

Comment: Please post your solution, and mark it as an answer - that stops ServerFault being left with "un-answered" questions that don't need any help.

Comment: When you ran `ssh-keygen`, you likely destroyed the previous key. Are you aware of why you even had one?

Answer (score 4):

This line
`Enter passphrase for key '/Users/emai/.ssh/id_rsa':`
means that your key is protected by a password entered when that key was generated
every time you use it it will ask for a password.

by running ssh-keygen one more time without entering the password you've generated another key.
No password in the key - no password prompt :)

here is quote from ssh-keygen manpage:

> *Normally this program generates the key and asks for a file in which to store the private key*.  The public key is stored in a file
>   with the same name but ``.pub'' appended.  The program also asks for a
>   passphrase.  The passphrase may be empty to indicate no passphrase (host keys must have an empty passphrase), or it may be a
>   string of arbitrary length.  A passphrase is similar to a password,
>   except it
>   can be a phrase with a series of words, punctuation, numbers, whitespace, or any string of characters you want.  Good passphrases
>   are 10-30 characters long, are not simple sentences or otherwise
>   easily
>   guessable (English prose has only 1-2 bits of entropy per character, and provides very bad passphrases), and contain a mix of
>   upper and lowercase letters, numbers, and non-alphanumeric characters.
>   The
>   passphrase can be changed later by using the -p option.
>
> *There is no way to recover a lost passphrase.*  If the passphrase is lost or forgotten, a new key must be generated and the
>   corresponding public key copied to other machines.

Comment: I've found that SSH will prompt for a passphrase if it has trouble reading the private key. I gave it an empty file, and it asked for a passphrase.

Comment: That  means you need to execute `ssh -v` to see the actual error, usually it is permissions problem, as the key file must have `0600` permissions.

Comment: It could also be that the user doesn't own the key file.  This often happens while copying the keys from other users.

Comment: @stimur 400 should be sufficient

Comment: Warning: at least on my ```OpenSSH_7.6p1 Ubuntu-4ubuntu0.3, OpenSSL 1.0.2n  7 Dec 2017```, openssh will ask for a passphrase even on a key that doesn't have a passphrase if there is no newline after the ```-----END OPENSSH PRIVATE KEY-----```  - just adding a newline after that makes it stop asking for a passphrase, weird stuff.

Answer (score 3):

Building on stimur's answer, yes, ssh is asking for a key's passphrase. Which means you are using a key in the first place.

If that is what you want - a private key protected with a passphrase, you can use `ssh-agent` to remember the passphrase (or the decrypted private key, I'm not sure which one), so that you can login without typing the passphrase again. You can remember it indefinitely, or for a fixed amount of time.

`man ssh-agent` and `man ssh-add`!

Comment: what if  I run ssh-agent, ssh-add and after running ssh command it still asks passphrase? And when I enter the passphrase, it even ask password, because it thinks that passphrase is wrong probably? If passphrase is wrong then ssh-add command would also not accept it.

Comment: Darius: either the passphrase is wrong, or you've got more than one key. Try the `ssh -v` option.

Comment: I tried -vvv. After it asks passphrase - it says "no passphrase give, try next key". But pashprhase is empty string, so I just hit enter. Then it writes "we did not send a packet, disable method" and "authmethod_lookup password" and after few messages it asks password. Tried entering '' and enter, then it says - bad passphrase. And I have more than one key, one is with passphrase, another is without passprase. But I pass to ssh command -i id_rsa and it should know that I use one without passphrase

Comment: @Darius.V: you can specify key explicitly by `-i /path/to/key` and check  verbose output of ssh, plus verify permissions for the key file. Please make sure you're using public key, not private.